# Django - default image not showing for imagefield

Tags: python, django, imagefield

So I have a page on my website in which I am displaying an image and if the user does not upload an image a default image is assigned. At the moment I am only trying to get default images to work but I can't seem to get it. My code is below and I will explain my thought process after.

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/joe/documents/exchange/Texchange/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

html page

```
{{ posting.image.url }}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}postings/nophoto.jpg"/>
```

I have read about multiple methods for displaying the image so I was trying 2 at once.

models.py

```
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/joe/documents/texchange/media/postings/', default="../../static/textchange/nophoto.jpg")
```

The file path /home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/media/postings/nophoto.jpg exists

The file path
/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/static/textchange/nophoto.jpg exists

This is what shows up where the photo should be plus there is a missing image box besides this (for if an image isn't found): /media/nophoto_tzD4Uib.jpg

So I thought that once I allow users to upload photos they would go to ../media/postings and that I should store the default in static files. Then are unique ID's assigned to photos in media/postings because users will be uploading multiple pictures once I upload. Also, why isn't the default image showing up?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: <img src="{{ posting.image.url }}" id="postimage">

Answer (score 0):

Such code will work for you.

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/joe/documents/exchange/Texchange/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'